# Export data in Excel sheet with column header using Java(Apache 3.10-FINAL)

Tags: java, excel, export-to-excel

I want to write the values in excel with heading and the associated values row wise like this:
[image]

This is what I am trying to do but I am not getting the desired output.

```
String[] rowHeadings = { "Roll no", "Name", "City", "Country", "Year"};


     String[][] values = new String[][] {
        new String[] {"101","Tyson","Tokyo","Japan","2nd"},
        new String[] {"102","Daichi","Kyoto","Japan","2nd"},
        new String[] {"103","Ray","Sapporo","Japan","2nd"},
        new String[] {"104","Kai","Osaka","Japan","2nd"},
        new String[] {"105","Max","Nagoya","Japan","2nd"}
};
for ( int i = 0; i < rowHeadings.length; i++ ) {
                Row headerColumn = sheet.createRow( i );
                //Cell cell = headerColumn.createCell(i);
                headerColumn.createCell( 1 ).setCellValue( rowHeadings[i] );
                int rownum = 0;
                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                int cellnum = 2;
                for(String[] columnValues : values){
                    for(String data : columnValues){
                        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                        cell.setCellValue( data);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am getting data like this :
[image]

Could please someone help me on how to populate the data column wise?

*This is not solved yet.

Comment: You do not show the code where you are inserting the data - hard to help.

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the row

Firstly you are doing

```
Row headerColumn = sheet.createRow( i ); // where i == 0
```

then later

```
int rownum = 0;
Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
```

As you have already created the row you do not need to do it again.

**edit**

You should be able to do this just using the top loop, doing something like (not tested)

```
for ( int i = 0; i < rowHeadings.length; i++ ) {
    Row headerColumn = sheet.createRow( i );
    headerColumn.createCell( 1 ).setCellValue( rowHeadings[i] );
    headerColumn.createCell( 1 ).setCellValue( values[i][0] );
    headerColumn.createCell( 1 ).setCellValue( values[i][1] );
    headerColumn.createCell( 1 ).setCellValue( values[i][2] );
    headerColumn.createCell( 1 ).setCellValue( values[i][3] );
    System.out.println(rowHeadings[i]);
}
```

Comment: Then while populating the data how it will come to next row. Let's say first row i.e roll no got populated then I need to do the same with Name.

Comment: I solved the previous issue by using this  Row row = sheet.getRow(i); as you told earlier not create row again. But , still facing issue while populating the data. I have updated the post. Could you please look into once?

Comment: each time you are doing `for(String[] columnValues : values){` you are starting at the beginning again.  Try my way?

Comment: It's returning only one row i.e country row.